# Newtonsoft.Json 'JArray.cs' does not exist

Tags: json, vb.net

Utilizando `VB.NET` e `Newtonsoft.Json` normalmente... de hora para outra apresentou o seguinte erro:

> Locating source for
>   'C:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Working-Signed\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Linq\JArray.cs'.
>   Checksum: SHA1 {c9 a6 9 0 23 6d 49 2 fc 49 eb 53 35 2b 81 cd 5f c 98
>   62} The file
>   'C:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Working-Signed\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Linq\JArray.cs'
>   does not exist. Looking in script documents for
>   'C:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Working-Signed\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Linq\JArray.cs'...
>   Looking in the projects for
>   'C:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Working-Signed\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Linq\JArray.cs'.
>   The file was not found in a project.

Comment: Se pode colocar o código ondem está ocorrendo o erro, apontando inclusive a linha.

Comment: '"SELECT id, idinterno, data, cel, nome, pedidostr, msg, Bxdo, origem FROM pedido WHERE Bxdo=0 ORDER BY id"
        '
        LinhaNaNuvem = LinhaNaNuvemX() 'Busca as linhas de pedidos que estao na nuvem, com        Bxdo<=0
            Dim array As New JArray 'Aqui ocorre o problema
            JArray.Parse(LinhaNaNuvem)")
            array = JArray.Parse(LinhaNaNuvem)
            For Each item As JObject In array   '   Aqui cada Item é um Pedido novo